# Create a Text-file in a Web App

Tags: javascript, web-applications, iframe, text-files

I am creating a Web App based on JavaScript and HTML5 for content curation work. The web App basically consists of 2 Iframes, when the end user drags data from one iframe to the other iframe(which is a HTML form). The other iFrame which has a HTML form has a "Generate" button.

Through this "Generate" button I want to save the data dragged into the form on the end-users computer as a Text File?

I don't want to use PHP as that would mean the end-user has to install a server. Is there a way to get a text file through a Web-App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly create a text-file on the clients computer. The main reason for this are security considerations: If every webpage would be allowed to save data on your computer without any intervention, you would get a big problem. There are multiple possibilites:

1. Offer the file as a download so the client can save it by himself.
2. Use Java: You can request the permission to save files on the harddisk from the user. This would involve a Java Applet. Due to its security risk, Java is not supported in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could help you. Try to use **FILE API** (working draft for html5)
[you can find it here](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/), and some [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)